# Is Xamarin Shell now a working product or is to too new to start using in Xamarin Forms apps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Some time ago I saw a blog post about a new feature called Xamarin shell.  But since then I have not seen or heard anything about it. Did that feature get included in the latest Xamarin forms? Are people using it? Are the promised features available or will we have to wait longer for it to be really usable?

Comment: Shell will be released in a couple of weeks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Xamarin.Forms 4.0 preview it's experimental you have to set the flag in `MainActivity.cs` of Android project:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental");
```

Comment: okay thanks.  That explains it then.  Do you have any idea when Xamarin Forms 4 stable will be coming out?

Comment: @Alan2 Well it is about to go live https://mybuild.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/77774

Comment: In the video mentioned above, note at 1:42 when @MaddyLagger says "Xamarin.Forms 4.0 is comming out in just a couple of weeks" (and the video is from May 7th). Also, note that the Xamarin.Forms road map (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Feature-Roadmap#400-aprilmay-2019) sets the release date of 4.0 somewhere between April/May. So... all that adds up to be released in the next two weeks...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the actual spec sheet regarding shell: [Shell Spec](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2415)

Here is the link to the GitHub issues page for Xamarin.Forms where you can see what errors have been reported for **Shell**: [Xamarin.Forms Issues](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Shell)

As I have been watching over the GitHub issue page the past few weeks, there have been quite a few issues reported about `Shell`. I would wait to use it in production until more of the issues that have been reported are solved, but it seems like quite a few people are trying it out!

Answer (score 0):

shell has been officially released in Xamarin 4.0 version and you can proceed with it as it is an amazing concept to work with you can get started with this given [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/shell-xamarin-forms-4-0-getting-started/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral)